# Why Android studio BumbleBee can't access databinding very often

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewbinding, android-studio-bumblebee

I am using Android Studio Bumblebee version and use viewbinding.

IDE is often can't access my layout file

After clean project everything is fine.
[image]
However, when I modify my layout file

this situation being more often(almost every minutes)

so I have to clean project again and again and again

Is there have any solution?

(My IDE version)

[image]

Comment: is it really available after cleaning ? i would imagine it's available after building

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes is cleaning, seldom situation is rebuild

Comment: It happened to me too in Bumblebee version but once you rebuild it the problem goes away. If it did not try restarting android Studio

Comment: @NandalaAbhinav Yes if I invalidate cache and restart the problem solves. But it also waste too much time to restart Android studio(clean project is fast)